# What is the appropriate extention for creating database in iOS?

Tags: ios, ios4, ios5, sqlite

I am creating a database application using the SQLite3 library.

I have created a database file using each of the file extensions: `.db`, `.sqlite`, and `.sql`.

All are working fine for me, but my question is which extension should I use in general?

Is there any difference between these file extentions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Sqlite documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/docs.html) seems to use the '.db' extension consistently, but I've seen plenty of Sqlite files that use '.sqlite' instead. Use whatever is meaningful to you. For example, if you're using Core Data to create the database, you might use '.cd' or .'coredata' to remind yourself not to modify the database outside of Core Data. Unless you're planning to transfer the file to some other machine (and really, even then) it won't matter.

Comment: as u say that >>" Unless you're planning to transfer the file to some other machine (and really, even then) it won't matter " means what?, I didnt get it.  I am creating application for iPhone and iPad so does it affect using diffrent extentions.

Comment: You can use any name for your database file. SQLite won't care. If you were going to build a feature into your app to transfer the database file to some other machine, perhaps by FTP or email, then it might make sense to use a file extension such as '.sqlite' that would make it easy for a human to realize that the file is a SQLite file. If you're not planning on doing that, it really doesn't matter what you name the file.

Answer (score 0):

The database will live in your application's sandbox, so users will never have to know about the filename or the extension, and other applications typically won't ever see it either. Just give it a distinct name so you can tell it apart from other files that your app might be saving to the same location.

Comment: @bneely- means there is no use of such extentions, so can I use any other appropriate extension.